# Movement of Box2d Body in cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, box2d, box2d-iphone

I need to move the box2d body according to position received form game center server.

After receiving position I just update the body position using: -

```
   Carbody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(serverposition.x,serverposition.y),0);
```

But its moving the body inapprotiate manner (for example. Body is showing somewere lese in the screen). At same time my sprite image not moving (attached with body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did to solve the positioning problem is i taken a normal sprite image and just change position in update with that box2d body position.

Eg:-

your carbody movement based on server position. it will move invisibly.
     your b2body without userdata(image)

```
carMainBody->SetTransform(b2Vec2(serverposition,carMainBody->GetPosition().y), 0.0f);
```

here your normal sprite image.  just attch your sprite image like this

```
 car->setPosition(ccp(carMainBody->GetPosition().x*PTM_RATIO,carMainBody->GetPosition().y*PTM_RATIO));
```

This method worked fine for me.